# How to find one template in several images?

Tags: python, opencv

I have one template and several images. So the problem is to find out is this template in the image or not. I wrote some loop, but I think it doesn't return Boolean value...

```
    for i in images:
        res = cv2.matchTemplate(i,templateDealer,cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
        min_val, max_val, min_loc, max_loc = cv2.minMaxLoc(res)
        top_left = max_loc
        bottom_right = (top_left[0] + w, top_left[1] + h)
        cv2.rectangle(i, top_left, bottom_right, (0, 255, 0), 2)
        result.append(res)
```

Please help me to make it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def getBestMatch():
images = [
    cv2.imread('tmp/1.png'),
    cv2.imread('tmp/2.png'),
    cv2.imread('tmp/3.png'),
    cv2.imread('tmp/4.png'),
    cv2.imread('tmp/5.png'),
    cv2.imread('tmp/6.png')
]
template = cv2.imread('template.png')

result = []
for i in images:
    match = cv2.matchTemplate(i, template, cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
    _, confidence, _, _ = cv2.minMaxLoc(match)
    result.append(confidence)

posNum = result.index(max(result))
return posNum
```

Answer (score 0):

`matchTemplate` returns a 2D array with the match values for each pixel location - how well the template matches that location.
`cv2.minMaxLoc(res)` returns the value and location of the best match in the image. It may not be an actual match when you compare it visually, but it is the highest value the algorithm returned. You can compare this highest value over multiple images, the highest overall is the one you seek.
Note: you should not use a normalizing algorithm for this, use `cv2.TM_CCOEFF` instead of `cv2.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED`

What you need to do is append a tuple that holds the highest value and it's location:
 `result.append((max_val, max_loc))`.
 After you have processed all images, find the highest max_val, and draw a rectangle using it's max_loc

Answer (score 0):

minMaxLoc will always give you something.

[image]

It totally depends on ur task. There are a few possibility I can think of

(1) You are looking for only 1 image of the most likely case among the N image.

In this case, concatenated all Image across one direction. Then run standard opencv tempalte matching and minmaxloc to find the most likely loation

```
vis = np.concatenate((img1, img2), axis=0) # do it for N image if necessary
```

(2) You are just want to check the similarity of the template to all N image.

Then you need to declare a threshold after minmax to see if there is a point in it that is above the threshold, if have return 1 if no return 0